# JSON notify invalid login details in android

Tags: php, android, json

I have a login code that is working fine and now I need to include a snippet of code that will toast the user if they give invalid login details.

Please help me to modify my code below (found it from other tutorial on the internet) so that it can get to inform the user if they provide invalid login details.

```
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
    String err=null;

    try {
        JSONObject root = new JSONObject(s);
        JSONObject user_data = root.getJSONObject("user_data");
        NAME = user_data.getString("name");
        PASSWORD = user_data.getString("password");
        EMAIL = user_data.getString("email");
        if(NAME == ""){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Invlaid Login Details", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        err = "Exception: "+e.getMessage();
    }

    Intent i = new Intent(ctx, Home.class);
    i.putExtra("name", NAME);
    i.putExtra("password", PASSWORD);
    i.putExtra("email", EMAIL);
    i.putExtra("err", err);
    startActivity(i);

}
```

and here is my php file for login

```
require 'connection.php';
try{

    $username = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'name');
    $pssword =  filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'password');

    if($username == "" )
    {
        $results = "Invalid Entry";
        echo json_encode(array("user_data"=>$results));
    }
    else
    {
        $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * '
                        . 'FROM users1 '
                        . 'WHERE name = :uname AND password = :password ');
        $stmt->bindParam(':uname', $username);
        $stmt->bindParam(':password', $pssword);
        $stmt->execute();
        $results = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        if($results > 0 ){

            $response = array();
            echo json_encode(array("user_data"=>$results));
        } else{
            $results = "No Record Found";           
            $results["success"] = 0;
            $results["message"] = "No Record Found";
             die(json_encode($results));
        }
        }

    }catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
$stmt = NULL;
$results = NULL;
exit();
//}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use

```
Name ==  ""
```

you have to use

```
"".equals(Name)
```

for comparing two String.

The == operator will compare the address value and "" doesn't have the same address of Name so you can never display your toast

Comment: Thanks but can you please expound this a little..? I am new in android programming and I would appreciate if you can give me a code that I need for this to work.. I changed the code to this and not sure if this will work.. if(NAME.equals(0))

Comment: Comparing two String in Java, it is not the same as in javascript or php. You have to use the method equals on the String class. If you don't use it, it will compare with address value and not the value. "" and Name are two distinct object so they have two address

Comment: It advice you should do the opposite. If("".equals(Name))

Answer (score 0):

Use NAME.isEmpty() for checking empty string

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the Android application. Don't worry I've done it in the past before you, so you're not the first to do it ;)

To validate that the field is empty, you need to use `name.isEmpty()` or `name.equals("")`. Remember that Android is a Java based program not like .NET.

The reason for this is because the JSON repsonse returned from the web service is an object not a string, so it will ignore this code: `name == ""`

Hope this helps :)